# How to run multiple service instances in different AppDomains?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, appdomain

I have implemented a windows service. 
How should I run multiple instances of the service, each in its own AppDomain ?

Comment: How would you run multiple instances of a service to begin with? As far as I know, all services are single instances. If you want a separate instance, I think you need to create an entirely new service, in which case it will get its own domain. Keep in mind that you can create multiple services that run the same executable (e.g. MS SQL Server)

Comment: Have a look at Windows Process Activation Service (http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/features-of-the-windows-process-activation-service-was). If it doesn't suit you look at COM+ which integrates with the .NET Framework and provides object pooling capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Services have to be registered before they can be run as services, so assuming you have a fixed number of instances to run, register each with a unique name when the service process is installed and then in your start up code, simply instance each one through ServiceBase.Run

ex:

```
            var service1= new MultiService("name1");
            var service2 = new MultiService("name2");

            ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { service1, service2 });
```

ServiceBase.Run automatically spins up each service in it's own appdomain.

Comment: I cannot find the appropriated documentation but `ServiceBase.Run` seems not to run each service on a separate `AppDomain`. Can you provide a source please.